# Getting 'E488: Trailing characters' With the following function

Tags: vim, neovim

Does anyone know why I'm getting the following error? I'm mapping the following function

```
function! ToggleCompileErrors()
         :if w:syntastic_is_open == 1
                 :call SyntasticReset()<CR>
                 let w:syntastic_is_open = 0
         :else
                 :call SyntasticCheck()<CR>
                 let w:syntastic_is_open = 1
         :endif
endfunction
```

With this command

```
command ToggleCompileErrors :call ToggleCompileErrors()
```

and it is getting called by the following keymapping

```
nnoremap <Leader>b :ToggleCompileErrors<CR>
```

And I don't know if it makes a difference but I am using neovim 0.2.2

Comment: Try removing `<CR>` from `call SyntasticCheck()<CR>`and `call SyntasticReset()<CR>`.

Answer (score 1):

*Watch your modes.* That `<CR>` [`:help key-notation`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/intro.txt.html#key-notation) is necessary for *mappings*, but not inside functions, which use *Ex commands*.

Likewise, you don't need to prefix commands inside a function with `:` (and this is rather odd here, especially because you're not even consistent about it). `:` is a *normal mode* command that enters *command-line mode*. As commands in a function already are Ex commands, the `:` is not needed.